# How to separate the dictionary with split values

Tags: python, dictionary

Dictionary is below

```
a = {'querystring': {'dataproduct.keyword': 'abc,def'}}
```

How to split into two dictionary with values?

`a['querystring'] = {'dataproduct.keyword': 'abc,def'}`

Expected out  while printing

```
{'dataproduct.keyword': 'abc'}
{'dataproduct.keyword': 'def'}
```

Since dictionary is hashmap
`[{'dataproduct.keyword': 'abc'} {'dataproduct.keyword': 'def'}]`

Disclaimer:

before executing need to check the comma

if `a['querystring'] = {'dataproduct.keyword': 'abc'}` then no need to split

if `a['querystring'] = {'dataproduct.keyword': 'abc,def,efg'}` if comma is there then only need to split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[{key: item} for key, value in a['querystring'].items() for item in value.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works with across all top-level entries, not just the entry with key `"querystring"`:

```
a = {'querystring': {'dataproduct.keyword': 'abc,def'}}
split_a = []

for value in a.values():
    for sub_key, sub_value in value.items():
        for split_sub_value in sub_value.split(","):
            split_a.append({sub_key: split_sub_value})
```

Resulting value of `split_a` is `[{'dataproduct.keyword': 'abc'}, {'dataproduct.keyword': 'def'}]`.